# Google Cloud Functions Used to Work Perfectly. Then They Stopped Working and Started Redirecting Me to A Login Page?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been using Google Cloud Functions for over a week now and they have been great. I used a simple python 3.9 function to print a string to my terminal in my Next.js app (for testing purposes) and it was working great. Here is my sample Google Cloud Function.

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Function ran'
```

And here is my Next.js code that calls the function:

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library"

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
    const url = process.env.FUNCTION_URL as string

    //Example with the key file, not recommended on GCP environment.
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({ keyFilename: process.env.KEYSTORE_PATH })

    //Create your client with an Identity token.
    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url)
    const result = await client.request({ url })
    console.log(result.data)
    res.json({ data: result.data })
}
```

I wrote another function to do the same thing and now every function just prints out raw html to the console? When I open the text in an index.html file it looks like this.
[image]

I rewrote the original cloud function exactly and even that doesn't work anymore. It prints that same html to the console. What is going on? My code is exactly the same and it breaks now...?

Comment: "My code is exactly the same and it breaks now...?" Did you try talking to Google technical support about this, or asking on a discussion forum specific to the cloud platform?

Comment: Can you share also the error logs?

Comment: Are you sure that the token that you are sending has rights to invoke the cloud function? Could it be that when you deployed earlier you deployed with the --allow-unauthenticated flag (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) while now you didnt?

Comment: Can you share also the error logs? - It's not throwing an error. In "view logs" there are no logs tagged error.

Are you sure that the token that you are sending has rights to invoke the cloud function? - Yeah, the working instance and the new one have the exact same permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple "needle in the haystack" type of fix. I was getting the function url from within the cloud function listing view, clicking the Actions Menu dropdown on the desired function, and selecting "Copy Function." This took me to the configuration display page where it had the function url in the "Trigger" section.
[image]

Notice what I circled in red. For some reason this page appends a `-1` to the function url. This is what made it fail for me. In my code I deleted the `-1` from the url stored in the `process.env.FUNCTION_URL` variable. That made it work!